# using sed to replace version in file

Tags: shell, sed

I want to replace string using sed command

```
/home/localuser/repository/xyz-1.8
```

xyz  version is not constant it will be changing . I want to change it with 1.9

I tried "`sed -i 's/repository/xyz-*/xyz-1.9/g' file.txt`"

I am getting output like this `"/home/localuser/repository/xyz-1.81.9/`

Why I am using repository/xyz* means i have two files with almost same words . I have repository/ in two lines .Please anyone provide solution for this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do like this:

```
echo "/home/localuser/repository/xyz-1.8" | sed  's/\(repository\/xyz-\).*/\11.9/g'
/home/localuser/repository/xyz-1.9
```

For inline file edit:

```
sed -i 's/\(repository\/xyz-\).*/\11.9/g' file.txt
```

You need to escape the `/` like this `\/`. Then back reference `\1` is used to retain the text.

Comment: @lokeswari cut and past problem, should work now. It will replace anything after `xyz-` with new number.